# SSL Breaks Message Inspector (WCF bug?)

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, idispatchmessageinspector

I have a custom message inspector that executes this line of code:

```
 public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
 {
     MessageBuffer contextPatch = request.CreateBufferedCopy(1024 * 128);
     ...
 }
```

The `CreateBufferedCopy` works fine when no security is enabled, but it throws an InvalidOperationException when SSL is configured.  The exception claims that the `Message request` object is in the "Written" state.  The configuration for all this is here:

```
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <clientCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" />
          <certificate findValue="sigtest.arbit.com" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
        </clientCertificate>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="sigtest.arbit.com" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
      </serviceCredentials>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceSecurityAudit auditLogLocation="Application" messageAuthenticationAuditLevel="Failure" serviceAuthorizationAuditLevel="Failure" suppressAuditFailure="true" />
      <endToEndLogging traceKeys="CorrelationId|correlationId" createDefaultRequestValue="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
```

This seems to be a bug in WCF itself.  That is, the `Message request` parameter should not be left (by SSL functionality?) in the "written" state.  Thoughts?

In case it is relevant, a custom binding was used for SSL:

```
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="myCustomBinding">
      <security defaultAlgorithmSuite="Default" authenticationMode="MutualCertificateDuplex" enableUnsecuredResponse="true" requireDerivedKeys="false" securityHeaderLayout="Lax" includeTimestamp="true" messageProtectionOrder="EncryptBeforeSign" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10" requireSignatureConfirmation="false" allowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply="true">
        <localClientSettings detectReplays="true" />
        <localServiceSettings detectReplays="true" />
      </security>
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
      <transactionFlow />
      <httpsTransport />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
```

Comment: Any update on this? Any additional light to shed on the problem?